# Comparing Strings with BREAK LINES in Java

Tags: java, string

I have two Strings as below:

```java
String A = "Hello World";
String B = "Hello \n World";
```

The only difference between the Strings is a line break, my question is how can we compare these strings by ignoring the line breaks.

Comment: You would need to remove `\n' from both strings using String.replace before comparing them using equals method.

Comment: Even ignoring the line break, they are still different: A has one space, B has two.

Answer (score 2):

I believe, that the following string should be equal: `"Hello World"` and `"Hello \nWorld"`.

The simplest way is to remove `\n` from the both strings and then use `isEquals()`:

```java
public static boolean isEquals(String one, String two) {
    one = one.replace("\n", "");
    two = two.replace("\n", "");
    return one.equals(two);
}
```

But it could be not efficient because here we have additional string object creations. Fortunately, you could use another approach.

```java
public static boolean isEquals(String one, String two) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (i < one.length() && j < two.length()) {
        if (one.charAt(i) == '\n')
            i++;
        else if (two.charAt(j) == '\n')
            j++;
        else if (one.charAt(i++) != two.charAt(j++))
            return false;
    }

    for (; i < one.length(); j++)
        if (one.charAt(i) != '\n')
            return false;

    for (; j < two.length(); j++)
        if (two.charAt(j) != '\n')
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A.equals(B.replaceAll("\n","").replaceAll("  "," "));
```

**String String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)**

Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given
replacement.

**boolean String.equals(Object anObject)**

Compares this string to the specified object.The result is true if and only if the argument is
not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.
For finer-grained String comparison, refer to java.text.Collator